# How to physically disable a soldered on wifi card to air-gap a Surface Laptop 4?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have a Surface Laptop 4 and I would like to air-gap it by physical means for security reasons. As in I don't want it to be physically capable to connect by WiFi even if it is already infected with something or someone targets it.

It seems to have a soldered on Intel ax201? WiFi adapter with an easily detachable antenna (sma plug).

Now disconnecting the antenna would be one solution but I guess the chip would still be able to connect to WiFi if it is held very close to a router.

How can I make sure I disable internet connectivity completely?
Any software means to completely brick the WiFi adapter?
Would deleting the driver work?
Would keeping the antenna connected and wrapping it in something work?

I have heard disconnecting the antenna to a WiFi adapter might harm the card somehow, does this pose any health hazards?

Comment: I doubt that disconnecting the antenna would harm the card, and am certain it does not pose any health hazards (A miniscule amount of Non-ionzing ration which now does not propogate.  If you are prone to believe that WIFi radiation has health risks, you are actually reducing the risk).    You risk shorting it, if you are not careful, but have you considered putting shielding above the chip - in the teardown I looked at it looks like a lot of the stuff around it is shielded, so finding a ground should be easy,

Comment: I am not afraid of electromagnetic waves per se, just wonder if the chip gets overheated whether it would hurt the chassis and the plastic might release some toxic gas or in some indirect way make the batteries explode or something. It sounds ridiculous but I don't want to tinker with machines I don't know as a rule of thumb. Maybe I'm just prone to anxiety.
Just covering the chip with some metal sounds dumb, would it actually work as in rendering it impossible to communicate even if it sits directly on the router?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the chip would overheat and hurt the chassis - I would not expect it to use a lot of power - although you would want to keep it disabled in software as well to prevent battery drain.  You should google "Farraday cage" and learn about RF shielding if you think covering the chip in metal is dumb.   You should also ask yourself why the other chips are covered in metal - hint - its to suppress RF - exactly what you want to do with the chip.  It would only shield the top of chip of-course - so it would decrease but probably not eliminate the range.

Comment: To permanently airgap it, de-solder the card from the board with a hot air blower from a soldering station, ensuring you apply the correct type of flux to the pads before doing so, cleaning up with a >90% solution of isopropyl alcohol after de-soldering, or send the motherboard to a company that can do so for you.

Comment: why not just disable it in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

1. Disconnecting the antenna only reduces the cards range somewhat, but does not prevent nearby connections (e.g., a laptop nearby).
2. One could find the *power* lead to the WiFi card and *carefully* cut the PCB trace to it, *if that trace is accessible* (not between layers). A sharp knife or rotary tool would work.
3. If this device *must* be air-gapped, I would not trust a software or driver hack. For that matter, I'd not trust a nonprofessional trying to convert a commodity PC into a secure device! Have you taken into account the [myriad ways](https://www.howtogeek.com/687792/the-ultimate-defense-what-is-an-air-gapped-computer/) information can get to and from a PC?

   - USB ports allow insertion of cables that might have a hidden RF device.
   - If the machine is out of sight for a few minutes, e.g., going through customs, a device can be placed in it.
   - Information can exfiltrate through [loudspeakers](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2334828-secure-computers-can-leak-data-by-using-speakers-to-shake-smartphones/), or even the [internal beeper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10319985).
   - The [display brightness can be modulated](https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/screens-brightness-leaking-data-air-gapped-computer) to leak data.
   - [Even the power supply radiates RF](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/air-gapped-pcs-vulnerable-to-data-theft-via-power-supply-radiation/) and can be used to extract data.

BTW, the Intel ax201 WiFi adapter seems to be only with edge-connector, not surface mount. Can you provide the actual make and model of the adapter?